# How to compare two DateTime to seconds?

Tags: c#, .net

How to compare two DateTime to seconds?

Comment: You might want to accept some answers. I'm sure in all those questions, someone had to answer more than just a couple.

Answer (score 44):

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now;
var date2 = new DateTime (1992, 6, 6);

var seconds = (date1 - date2).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: (int)(date1 - date2).TotalSeconds will prevent fractions of a second from being used

Answer (score 39):

Do you mean comparing two `DateTime` values *down to the second*? If so, you might want something like:

```
private static DateTime RoundToSecond(DateTime dt)
{
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day,
                        dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
}

...

if (RoundToSecond(dt1) == RoundToSecond(dt2))
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, to find out whether the two DateTimes are within a second of each other:

```
if (Math.Abs((dt1 - dt2).TotalSeconds) <= 1)
```

If neither of these help, please give more detail in the question.

Comment: I like RoundToSecond method, it makes it very clear what is happening when you call it

Comment: Sorry, I do not like the RoundToSecond method...IMO it should be called something like "TruncateToSecond", because here it's just cutting off the milliseconds. If I were to see RoundToSecond I would expect a DateTime like "2022-07-25 20:53:27.99926" to _round_ to "2022-07-25 20:53:28", but instead you get "2022-07-25 20:53:27"

Comment: @Seth: Then you should feel absolutely free to call it that in your code. I'm not going to start editing an answer from 12 years ago for that reason.

Answer (score 17):

If you subtract one date from another, it returns a `TimeSpan` which has a `TotalSeconds` property. So:

```
double seconds = (Date1 - Date2).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Seconds is not the same as TotalSeconds.

Comment: I posted and edited there and then. :) Thanks for pointing out though.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime start = DateTime.now;
DateTime end = DateTime.end;
TimeSpan dif = end - start;
```

dif will be of the form 0:0:0:0 where the third value is seconds.