# DateTime.Compare fail when time is equal in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am comparing datetime excluding seconds.Both datetime values are equal for compare condition fails.[image]

```
     DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]).AddSeconds(-Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]).Second);
     DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-DateTime.Now.Second);

  if (properties.ListItem["Modified"] != null && DateTime.Compare(d1,d2)!= 0)
  {
     //If condition still executes even after dates are equal.
```

Comment: Seconds being equal does not mean milliseconds are

Comment: You're excluding seconds. But forgetting about MilliSeconds and Ticks. Two datetimes are considered equal when `DateTime.Ticks` property are equal. In your case, probably they are not.

Comment: Your 2 invocations of DateTime.Now is a race condition.

Comment: You could just do `d1.Date == d2.Date && d1.Hour == d2.Hour && d1.Minute == d2.Minute`

Comment: Try rounding to the nearest second, if you want to compare if they are to the same second (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816163/how-to-compare-two-datetime-to-seconds), but as @kai mentioned you'll still have a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your milliseconds and ticks are not equal.

Use

```
public void AreEqual(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
     return d1.Date == d2.Date && d1.Hour == d2.Hour && d1.Minute == d2.Minute;
}
```

or

```
public void AreEqual(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
     return d1.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") == d2.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
}
```

In the latter you can edit the format parameter to determine your equality instead of long chains of properties of the datetime objects.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about milliseconds part.
Here is the function that correctly truncates DateTime to whole minutes:

```
static DateTime TrancateToMinutes(DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.Date.AddMinutes((int)dt.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension methods to pull only date and time by excluding sec and millisecs for ex

```
public static DateTime ZeroMilliseconds(this DateTime value) 
{
  return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, 
    value.Hours, value.Minutes, value.Seconds);
}
```